# Facebook Share Button equal to Twitter Tweet Button

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, button, twitter

I made a working Twitter "Tweet" button through: https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet (which indeed does appear on my site on localhost) and really need a Facebook "Share" button that matches it in color scheme, font type/color, and highlight effects. However:

-The button generated by Facebook's code here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/ does not seem editable by CSS, so I can't get it to look just like the Twitter button I have.

Would love some help, thanks!

***EDIT As requested, here are some code snippets to aid in those wanting to help me:

Twitter button I'm using:

```
 <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-    
url="http://example.com" data-size="large" data-count="none" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)
[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)) 
{js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

...and here's what Facebook code I'm starting with:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="75" data-type="button"></div>
```

Comment: Just put it up on there too. Doesn't look like there are many users there though. The "CSS" tag has 96 uses there and over 188,000 uses here.

Comment: ...And someone just left a comment there that it belongs here. Please remove negative vote, it is probably causing people to think this isn't a coding-related question and it is.

Comment: This isn't a UX question as is, as it appears OP has a clear idea of what he wants to present to his users and how they are to interact, and instead he is having difficulties in effecting the code to achieve his intended design.

Comment: Tip- Post code snippet here of what you've already done, people will be more likely to help. Its much easier if we can just copy and paste your snippet into jsfiddle or codepen and modify from there

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the Facebook buttons don't have editable css because Facebook wants their styles on their buttons.

That said, **you can get around the styling limitations using the unsupported* facebook sharer.php** link. Basically, it's the old version of the share button, and while you can't define as many things (or get callbacks etc. when the share happens) because it's regular html a tag, you can style it however you dang well want.

For a rundown of how to customize the link's parameters, **[check out this blog post](http://ar.zu.my/how-to-really-customize-the-deprecated-facebook-sharer-dot-php/)**.

**While Facebook has deprecated sharer.php, and really wants people to use the new versions so Facebook can control styling etc., they are still keeping it alive because it has such wide usage across the web. YMMV, but it's currently the only way I'm aware of to style a Facebook share button.*